# Update values of an array of dictionaries from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a this array of dictionaries:

```
jsn = [{'ID' : '01', 'Item' : 'Apple', 'salesman' :'Johnny'},
       {'ID': '02', 'Item': 'carrot', 'salesman':'Patricia'}, 
       {'ID': '04', 'Item' : 'airplane', 'salesman' : 'Eddgard'}, 
       {'ID' : '05', 'item' : 'iron', 'salesman' : 'Bettany'}]
```

and i also have this dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["1", "apple"], ["2", "mango"], 
                    ["3", "melon"], ["4", "watermelon"], 
                    ["5", "strawberry"]],columns=["ID", "Item"])
```

i want to change all the "Item" Values from the jsn array based on the df1 "Item" values.

I've tried this approach

```
for k in df1:
   for i in jsn1:
        i.update({'Item': f"{k}"})
```

But it didn't work as i've expected.

Comment: that is a list, not an array

Comment: The ids are mismatched between those structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame( [["1", "apple"], ["2", "mango"], ["3", "melon"], ["4", "watermelon"], ["5", "strawberry"]],columns=["ID", "Item"] )
jsn = [{'ID' : '01', 'Item' : 'Apple', 'salesman' :'Johnny'},{'ID': '02', 'Item': 'carrot', 'salesman':'Patricia'}, {'ID': '04', 'Item' : 'airplane', 'salesman' : 'Eddgard'}, {'ID' : '05', 'Item' : 'iron', 'salesman' : 'Bettany'}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(jsn)

df1["Item"] = df1["Item"].str.lower()
df2["Item"] = df2["Item"].str.lower()

df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='Item')
```

Output:

| ID_x | Item | ID_y | salesman |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | apple | 01 |
| 1 | 2 | mango | NaN |
| 2 | 3 | melon | NaN |
| 3 | 4 | watermelon | NaN |
| 4 | 5 | strawberry | NaN |

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
for dict_ in jsn:
    dict_["Item"] = df1[df1.ID.astype(int) == int(dict_["ID"])].Item.values[0]

jsn
```

Output:

```
[{'ID': '01', 'Item': 'apple', 'salesman': 'Johnny'},
 {'ID': '02', 'Item': 'mango', 'salesman': 'Patricia'},
 {'ID': '04', 'Item': 'watermelon', 'salesman': 'Eddgard'},
 {'ID': '05', 'Item': 'strawberry', 'salesman': 'Bettany'}]
```

Comment: I don't think "airplane" should become "melon", maybe rather "watermelon" given the 4/04 ID?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
ref = df1.set_index('ID')['Item']

for d in jsn:
    d['Item'] = ref.get(str(int(d['ID'])), d.setdefault('Item', None))
    # or
    # d['Item'] = ref.get(d['ID'].lstrip('0')), d.setdefault('Item', None))
```

Updated `jsn`:

```
[{'ID': '01', 'Item': 'apple', 'salesman': 'Johnny'},
 {'ID': '02', 'Item': 'mango', 'salesman': 'Patricia'},
 {'ID': '04', 'Item': 'watermelon', 'salesman': 'Eddgard'},
 {'ID': '05', 'Item': 'strawberry', 'salesman': 'Bettany'}]
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but the jsn doesn't update. How do you assign the new value to the 'jsn' variable?

Comment: because of mutability of the dictionaries in `jsn`. This works well for me with your provided inputs (except the last dictionary as you use `item` instead of `Item`)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  `dict` base `df1`. then update each `dict` in `jsn` like the below:

```
jsn = [{'ID' : '01', 'Item' : 'Apple', 'salesman' :'Johnny'},{'ID': '02', 'Item': 'carrot', 'salesman':'Patricia'}, {'ID': '04', 'Item' : 'airplane', 'salesman' : 'Eddgard'}, {'ID' : '05', 'Item' : 'iron', 'salesman' : 'Bettany'}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame( [["2", "mango"], ["3", "melon"], ["4", "watermelon"], ["5", "strawberry"]],columns=["ID", "Item"] )


dct = dict(zip(df1['ID'].astype(int), df1['Item']))
for j in jsn:
        j['Item'] = dct.get(int(j['ID']), j['Item'])
print(jsn)
```

---

```
[{'ID': '01', 'Item': 'Apple', 'salesman': 'Johnny'},
 {'ID': '02', 'Item': 'mango', 'salesman': 'Patricia'},
 {'ID': '04', 'Item': 'watermelon', 'salesman': 'Eddgard'},
 {'ID': '05', 'Item': 'strawberry', 'salesman': 'Bettany'}]
```